# MySQL Incorrect AT value using current_timestamp with event scheduler

Tags: mysql, timestamp, scheduler

I'm trying to configure a one time event with MySQL scheduler using current_timestamp.

The query is the following one (the second number may vary)

```
CREATE EVENT event_name ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 30
DO UPDATE test_table SET value = 0 WHERE id = 1;
```

It sometimes works but I'm often having the following error.

```
 #1525 - Incorrect AT value: '20211031204269'
```

It seems that the issue comes from the fact that seconds are directly added to current_timestamp and thus having '68' as seconds value in this example

Is there a way for MySQL to correctly create the timestamp using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [+ seconds]` notation (by incrementing minutes when seconds are greater than 60, same for minutes, hours, days...) or do I have to generate the timestamp by myself ?

Comment: you must change **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 30** to **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 SEC** see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-and-time-units/ for the units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thirty what exactly,

you need to specify the interval you want to add with a timestamp

> interval:
> quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
> WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
> DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)

```
CREATE EVENT event_name ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE 
DO UPDATE test_table SET value = 0 WHERE id = 1;
```